# Can Mac users cache Windows Authentication credentials?

Tags: mac, windows-authentication

We have an intranet site that we set our Windows users up with as a trusted site and then they don't have to enter in their credentials when they visit.  We have Mac clients, not joined to the domain, but have AD credentials, that we allow to authenticate to the site.  The only problem is they have to authenticate each time they come back.  Is there a way on a Mac to store Windows credentials that they use to access the intranet site so they don't have to enter them in every time?

Comment: I don't believe so.  Windows does this because it can look at the already authenticated user itself.

Comment: So even though they can authenticate, the Mac can't keep that token on the machine?

Comment: that is correct.  How you attach OS X to a active domain is entirely different

Comment: By "intranet site", you mean a webserver, right?  If so, the Mac users should be able to let their credentials be saved by the browser, so the browser will authenticate for them.  This should work even for IIS's "Windows Authentication" (NTLM).  OS X can save the password in the Keychain.  I think it might be a separate Keychain entry per website though, so if you have a password-rotation policy, they'll need to re-enter/re-save their new passwords after each change.